# How make a REPL for a compiler made with Reflection.Emit?

Tags: .net, compiler-construction, f#, read-eval-print-loop

Making a repl for a interpreter is trivial. However, I wonder how do the same for a compiler. I see how LLVM can work both-ways and exist REPL for compiled languages like C, but don't grasp how is that posible.

I'm building a toy language in F#, so wonder how do the same (ie: If compile to .NET bytecode) if I generate assemblies with reflection emit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the REPL for compiled languages works is generally that it emits the code and immediately runs it. When you use F# Interactive, the F# code is parsed, type checked and compiled (as usual), but rather than saving it to a file it just keeps the generated assembly in memory and it runs the code immediately. I think the C# REPL actually saves the assembly somewhere to disk and then immediately loads the code from there.

- The simplest entry point for this is probably the `DynamicMethod` type in .NET (see the [MSDN documentation with a sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod(v=vs.110).aspx). You can use it to emit IL code, wrap it into a delegate and invoke it.
- If you need to emit types (not just method bodies), then you'll need the `DefineDynamicAssembly` method (see [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs22fky4(v=vs.110).aspx)) which lets you define assemblies with types.

An alternative would be to build your language on top of Roslyn or F# Quotations, but if you're already compiling to .NET bytecode, then the above should do the trick.